# Is there a way to proxy requests in Parcel as in Webpack?

Tags: parceljs

In Webpack there is an ability to proxy backend requests through `proxy` setting in the config file. That allows me to develop a front-end part of my app with webpack-dev-server with HMR while webpack-dev-server and my app server run on different ports on my localhost. There is also a development server in Parcel which is run by default command `parcel index.html` on port 1234. Is there a way to run both Parcel dev server and proxy requests to my app server?

I found a solution that suggests using Express middleware for that. But that doesn't solve the problem completely and cleanly. What if my backend runs Django? How should I use Parcel dev server then?

Comment: Just for reference: work was started on this... https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/2477

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not supported directly, see the open pull-request https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/2477

However, https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/55 and lists various solutions involving a simple wrapper, such as:

for `http-proxy-middleware` >= 1.0.0 (Published 2/2020):

```js
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');


const app = express();

app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

const bundler = new Bundler('src/index.html');
app.use(bundler.middleware());

app.listen(Number(process.env.PORT || 1234));
```

For older `http-proxy-middleware` (versions 0.x):

```js
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

app.use('/api', proxy({
  target: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
}));

const bundler = new Bundler('src/index.html');
app.use(bundler.middleware());

app.listen(Number(process.env.PORT || 1234));
```

Comment: perfect resolver ! thank you sir ! this is the best way to proxy parcel !

Comment: it is supported now, see https://parceljs.org/features/development/#api-proxy

Answer (score 2):

There is an npm module called [parcel-proxy-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-proxy-server) that might help. I have tried it myself, and it works quite well for my project.

From the documentation:
Create a file, e.g. **server.js**

```
const ParcelProxyServer = require('parcel-proxy-server');

// configure the proxy server
const server = new ParcelProxyServer({
  entryPoint: './path/to/my/entry/point',
  parcelOptions: {
    // provide parcel options here
    // these are directly passed into the
    // parcel bundler
    //
    // More info on supported options are documented at
    // https://parceljs.org/api
    https: true
  },
  proxies: {
    // add proxies here
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://example.com/api'
    }
  }
});

// the underlying parcel bundler is exposed on the server
// and can be used if needed
server.bundler.on('buildEnd', () => {
  console.log('Build completed!');
});

// start up the server
server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Parcel proxy server has started');
});
```

then call `node server.js` to run your proxy, and the default parcel command.